# How to find a number character (e.g. \d) excluding a number (e.g. 3)

Tags: regex

I want to search a text file for three consecutive numbers that do not match "327".  I was going to use [012456789][013456789][012345689] but i think there's a way to do it using \d.  Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
^(?!327)\d{3}$
```

Comment: thanks!  that helped a lot.  Wasn't familiar with lookahead before this